# Noun is a noun (terminology)

Tags: grammar, nouns

Is there any particular term for when we use one noun to describe/define another.

> Karl is **a teacher**
>
> Pigeons are **birds**.

Basically, the format being “x is y”.

Is there a name for the concept, the type of sentence, the noun in this position, or any other related terminology?

It makes me think of an apposite noun, but I don’t believe this counts as that..?

Comment: The noun after the auxiliary verb _is_ is called a _predicate noun_ or predicate nominal or predicate noun phrase. The noun before the auxiliary verb is called the subject or the subject noun phrase.

Comment: Superb. So could one say that we can describe people with adjectives and with predicate nouns. Would that be accurate?

Comment: We can describe people with any word at all. That's what most words are for. If you're looking for a definition for _noun_, it doesn't have anything to do with what it refers to -- it's entirely about its use in a sentence. Nouns can be subjects and objects and objects of prepositions, and they can be modified by articles. That's pretty much it.

Comment: I think the "is a" relationship is termed a *coupla*, plural *copulae*. But that's obviously not a term for the noun.

Comment: Yes, the noun phrases "a teacher" and "birds" are called 'subjective predicative complements'. The noun phrase that a predicative complement relates to is called the predicand. In your example, "Karl" and "Pigeons" are the predicands. Clauses like this with "be" as predicator are called 'copular' clauses.

Comment: @DanBron yes.  Familiar with copula, but as you say, it doesn’t really play into what I was looking for here.

Comment: @JohnLawler yes, of course. Not really looking for a “definition for noun” but rather a term for the role the noun is playing in this case, which you have provided. Thanks.

Comment: Does none of you want to have a swing at the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is some terminology in *logic* for these kinds of statements.

> Karl is a teacher.

This is **a singular membership proposition**: a proposition asserting that **an individual** (in this case Karl) is member of **a category** (teachers).

---

> Pigeons are birds.

meaning

> All pigeons are birds.

This is **an A-form categorical proposition**: a proposition asserting that all of the members of one category, **the subject term** (pigeons), are included in another category, **the predicate term** (birds).

In logic, **the predicate** in this example is the function “is a bird”, which takes an individual as an argument (the subject), and outputs “true” or “false”.

There are 4 standard forms of categorical propositions:

- **A-form**: All *S* are *P*.
- **E-form**: No *S* are *P*.
- **I-form**: Some *S* are *P*.
- **O-form**: Some *S* are not *P*.

*Quantity*: A-form and E-form categorical propositions are **universal**, I-form and O-form categorical propositions are **particular** (or **existential**).

*Quality*: A-form and I-form categorical propositions are **affirmative**, E-form and O-form categorical propositions are **negative**.

---

> Karl is a teacher.
>
> Pigeons are birds.

In *grammar*, both sentences consist of **a subject** (“Karl”, “Pigeons”), **a copula** (“is”, “are”) and **a predicative complement** (“a teacher”, “birds”).

Both a subject and a predicative complement can be much longer than just a noun. A predicative complement can also consist of just an adjective, or an adjective phrase.